Only One Time Mapping Issue
I need help about my slam_toolbox mapping issue.
I am using ros2 humble distro and slamtec s2 lidar and for mapping slam_toolbox.
When ı run my lidar and slam toolbox laser and toolbox working and mapping once time.
But when ı move my lidar laser scan changes but map not updating same map staying on screen.
How ı can fix that problem u look much sites docs but cant solve?

can you share the slam_toolbox config file with us. And also do you have an imu sensor or any other setup that publishes to /odom topic.
